# why my appended list is overwriting I mean the previous appended element is changing?Can I know why

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I tried this code
created a function and again callimg the same fuction until x<5

```py
def appen(m,x): 
    print(m)
    l1.append(m)
    print(l1)
    while(x<5):
        m.append(x)
        appen(m,x+1)
        break;
```

input for the above function

```
i/p :input  
n=[]  
l1=[]  
appen(n,1)
```

Actual output

```
o/p  
[]  
[[]]  
[1]  
[[1], [1]]  
[1, 2]  
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]  
[1, 2, 3]  
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  
[1, 2, 3, 4]  
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

This is what I expected

expected o/p: output

```
[]  
[[]]  
[1]  
[[], [1]]  
[1, 2]  
[[], [1], [1, 2]]  
[1, 2, 3]  
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]  
[1, 2, 3, 4]  
[[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It is not clear what is going on in your example.

Comment: DYZ , check the post again I edited it. It hope it is clear to you

Comment: I still believe your code is incorrectly formatted. Where does your function `appen`  end? Is it indeed recursive?

Comment: Yes DYZ, it is recursive until x<5  after that I have provided the break statement otherwise it would be an infinite loop and I didn't return anything from the function because I didn't want. Actually my question is what is happening with l.append(m) see the actual o/p I think I am missing some main concept in python can you please help me to figure out that

Comment: You should have used `if` instead of `while`. `while` implies there is a loop, but you do not have a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the lists are mutable...The values of the list changes everytime when you append a new value.So `copy()` function will help you to copy the list.Thus no modification occurs..This code will help you...

```
def func(n):
m_lst=[]
lst=[]
print(m_lst)
m_lst.append(lst.copy())
print(m_lst)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    lst.append(i)
    m_lst.append(lst.copy())
    print(m_lst)
func(4)
```

Output:

```
[]
[[]]
[[], [1]]
[[], [1], [1, 2]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Srikesh In the above code if I used l1.append(m.copy())  output is desired but I didn't understand how the previous values appended to the list are changed every time we added a new value.

Comment: Python Lists are mutable which means when you take any actiion like appending,deleting it can do unlike tuple...If you have an empty list and appending a element and it becomes an non-empty list..if u copy the list ..it will store current values in another storage place....Kindly Upvote my answer....